# How to define composed id for an api resource in api-platform?

Tags: api-platform.com

I made an API resource which is not connected to a database table. I have a custom item data provider for it. I need a composed identifier for that resource. In the resource's class, I set for 3 properties the @ApiProperty(identifier=true): platform, platform version, and app version. But the generated method for getting the item has only one id. The path generated for it is /versionInfos/{id}.

> Do I have any solution to make a automatically generated path like:
>   `/versionInfos/{platform}/{platformVersion}/{appVersion}`?